# form submit javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

my html is

```
<form id="login" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false" method="post" >
                <fieldset>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="username">Usuario :</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username"/>
                    </div>                                  
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">                                      
                        <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
                        <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password"/> 
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit"  data-theme="b" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
                </fieldset>

           </form>
```

and my javascript is

```
$("#login").submit(function(){
alert("OK");
}
```

but it isn't working.

i have check in http://jsfiddle.net/w2Sqs  and it works, but in my web not!

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is empty. Besides, what is not working? what is your expected output? what is your current result? not working u mean no alert? or the form is not submitting?

Comment: Did you include the jQuery core library?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w2Sqs/   I am using :   jquery-1.9.1.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js , i want submit a form, but its not work only reload a page, not execute alert("OK") and i dont have any message in console browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably referencing your form too soon.  If you try and reference a DOM element before it is loaded, then it's going to fail to attach a listener to it.

Instead, either put the selector below your form:

```
   <body>
      <form id="login" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="user">
         <input type="submit" value="send">
      </form>
      <script>
         $("#login").submit(function() {
            alert("ok");
         });
      </script>
   </body>
```

Or make sure the DOM is loaded completely using the **[jQuery ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** stuff (This code can go in the `<head>` section):

```
     $(function() {
        $("#login").submit(function() {
           alert("ok");
        });
     });
```

Comment: @luisbg No problem, JSFiddle usually causes all of your code to run after the DOM finishes loading which is why it worked on the fiddle, but not whenever you ran it alone.  I ran into this myself a while back.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding an event to your submit function

```
$(#id).submit(function(event){});
```

Comment: not working, $("#login").submit(function(event){
    alert("Hey, who clicked me?");
});

Comment: As indicated by above comments, how does your jquery include look?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: If you are pulling this directly from the web, then include http:// infront of both ..code for jquery and mobile.

Comment: Not found, but i put scipt direct in index.html WORKS!!! but if i write in main.js not working! Any idea?

Comment: how are you calling the script, main.js, in your index.html?